# ElasticSearch RestClient response to ResponseHits API instead of Response API not working

Tags: java, elasticsearch, elastic-stack, rest-client

Am fetching documents from elasticsearch via `RestClient` Java API and trying to get the response in `ResponseHits`, so that am able to handle multiple documents (in response) using below code.

`SearchHit[] contentSearchHits = contentSearchResponse.getHits().getHits();`

But am not able to set the `RestClient` response in `ResponseHits` API. From Eclipse am getting this message `Type mismatch: cannot convert from Response to ResponseHits`.

If i use `RestHighLevelClient` am able to use `ResponseHits` class and everything goes good. But am not using it, due to `BUFFER_SIZE` limitation to 100MB by default, where i need more `BUFFER_SIZE`.

So, is there anyway to handle `RestClient` response if it is returning multiple doucments while searching.

Please find my Java Code that am using to fetching documents from ElasticSearch.

```
private final static String ATTACHMENT = "document_attachment";
    private final static String TYPE = "doc";
    static long BUFFER_SIZE = 520 * 1024 * 1024;   //  <---- set buffer to 520MB instead of 100MB


    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        RestClient restClient = null;
        Response contentSearchResponse=null;
        String responseBody = null;
        JSONObject source = null;
        String path = null;
        String filename = null;
        int id = 0;
        ResponseHits responseHits = null;

        RestClientBuilder builder =  null; 

        try {

        restClient = RestClient.builder(
                        new HttpHost("localhost", 9200, "http"),
                        new HttpHost("localhost", 9201, "http")).build();

        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        SearchRequest contentSearchRequest = new SearchRequest(ATTACHMENT); 
        SearchSourceBuilder contentSearchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
        contentSearchRequest.types(TYPE);
        QueryBuilder attachmentQB = QueryBuilders.matchQuery("attachment.content", "activa");
        contentSearchSourceBuilder.query(attachmentQB);
        contentSearchSourceBuilder.size(50);
        contentSearchRequest.source(contentSearchSourceBuilder);

        Map<String, String> params = Collections.emptyMap();
        HttpEntity entity = new NStringEntity(contentSearchSourceBuilder.toString(), ContentType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        HttpAsyncResponseConsumerFactory.HeapBufferedResponseConsumerFactory consumerFactory =
                new HttpAsyncResponseConsumerFactory.HeapBufferedResponseConsumerFactory((int) BUFFER_SIZE);


        try {
            //contentSearchResponse = restClient.performRequest("GET", "/document_attachment/doc/_search", params, entity, consumerFactory); //  this is working with single document, not sure how to handle if request is returning multiple documents while searching.
            responseHits  = restClient.performRequest("GET", "/document_attachment/doc/_search", params, entity, consumerFactory); // am not able to set the response to `ResponseHits` class
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        } 

        try {
            responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(contentSearchResponse.getEntity());
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        System.out.println("Converting to JSON");
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(responseBody);
        JSONObject  hits = jsonObject.getJSONObject("hits");
        JSONArray hitsArray=hits.getJSONArray("hits");
        for(int i=0;i<hitsArray.length();i++) {
            JSONObject obj= hitsArray.getJSONObject(i);
            source = obj.getJSONObject("_source");
            id = Integer.parseInt(source.opt("id").toString());
            path = source.optString("path");
            filename = source.optString("filename");

        }

        JSONObject jsonBody = new JSONObject();
        jsonBody.put("id", id);
        jsonBody.put("path", path);
        jsonBody.put("filename", filename);
        System.out.println("Response --->"+jsonBody.toString());

        }
```

Am using ElasticSearch Version 6.2.3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the way to handle multiple documents from `RestClient`  response

```
             JSONArray hitsArray;
             JSONArray responseArray = new JSONArray();
             JSONObject responseObj;
             String fileRelativePath=null;

             JSONObject json = new JSONObject(responseBody);
             JSONObject hits = json.getJSONObject("hits");
             hitsArray = hits.getJSONArray("hits");
                for (int i=0; i<hitsArray.length(); i++) {
                JSONObject h = hitsArray.getJSONObject(i);
                JSONObject sourceJObj = h.getJSONObject("_source");
                        responseObj = new JSONObject();
                        fileRelativePath = sourceJObj.optString("path").toString().concat(sourceJObj.optString("filename").toString());
                        responseObj.put("id", Integer.parseInt(sourceJObj.opt("id").toString()));
                        responseObj.put("fileRelativePath", fileRelativePath);
                        responseArray.put(responseObj);

                }
                System.out.println("Response Length -->"+responseArray.length()+"Response --->"+responseArray.toString());
```